# Doubt regarding Interval probability in the case of Joint CDF

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables. Let $F_{XY}(x,y)$ be the joint CDF and $f_{XY}(x,y)$ be the PDF. I can imagine that the probability corresponding to the region given in picture is the volume element of the PDF under this region. 
[image]

But I am looking for the probability using CDF. So the probability to fall under this area is given as $F_{XY}(x_2,y_2)-F_{XY}(x_2,y_1)-F_{XY}(x_1,y_2)+F_{XY}(x_1,y_1)$  in [this pdf file](http://www2.imperial.ac.uk/~naheard/C245/jointly_distributed_random_variables_article.pdf).
But how?

How can I derive that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the definition $F_{XY}(a,b)=\Pr[X\le a, Y\le b]$ and see what combinations of probability events generates the square in your picture.

Hint: draw a picture of the region $[X\le a, Y\le b]$.

Comment: I got the answer, due to your help.

Comment: @dexterdev: you can accept the answer (by clicking the check mark) if a better answers appears later you still can change it later